# How to install Mahout on Windows 8.1?

Tags: cygwin, sql-server, hadoop

My goal is to build up a recommendation system and after going through many articles, I came across **Mahout** as a simple, yet effective way to go on. I already have **XAMPP** installed on my system.

How can I install Mahout? I need the complete instructions since I have neither worked with cygwin before, nor have I worked with Hadoop, and everywhere I see, I see these two mentioned very frequently. I first need to install it on my localhost before going on installing it on the server.

Comment: The installaton instructions would be exactly the same as if you were running it on any other version of Windows.  What part of the installation are you confused about?

Comment: I couldn't find proper documentation of Windows installation, be it any version

Comment: This link was on the build instructions on the Mahout website http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/ You shouldn't need cygwin considering its a java application.  You will have to follow the Hadoop build and installation instructions also.